# Why do I get error on if else statements

Tags: java

why do my last two if statements have illegal start of expression and else without if errors? also I cannot post my code here because it wants formatting and I do not know how to do it properly. how do I post an actual code view?

I have changed it and this is the edited code. thank you for all of your help.

```
   //Import Java scanner
import java.util.Scanner;

//This class ask a user for their item count and informs the user of the best packing method.
public class PackingOrganizer{
 public static void main(String[] args){
//declare constants and variables
int CARTONS = 4, BOXES = 5;
double containerAmount;
double containerAmount2;
//Get users item count
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number of items : (All partial items are to be rounded up. ex. 6.5 items is rounded to 7 items)");
double itemCount = input.nextDouble();

//Check to see if input is an integer value
if (itemCount != (int) itemCount)
 System.out.println("Invalid input round all partial numbers up");
//processing phase
  else if (itemCount % CARTONS == 0){
      containerAmount =( itemCount /CARTONS );
      System.out.println("Cartons can be used. The " + itemCount + " items will require " + containerAmount + " cartons ");}
  else if (itemCount % BOXES ==0){
      containerAmount = (itemCount / BOXES);
      System.out.println("Boxes can be used. The " + itemCount + " items will require " + containerAmount + " Boxes ");}
  else if ((itemCount % BOXES != 0) && (itemCount % CARTONS != 0))
      System.out.println("Neither boxes nor cartons can be used for your: " + itemCount + " items.");
  else if ((itemCount % BOXES == 0) && (itemCount % CARTONS == 0 ));{
      containerAmount = (itemCount/BOXES);
      containerAmount2 = (itemCount/CARTONS);
      System.out.println("Cartons can be used. The " + itemCount + " items will require " + containerAmount2 +"." + " Boxes can be used. The " + itemCount + " items will require" + containerAmount +" boxes ");}
 }
}
```

Comment: Copy paste your code, select it and click the `{}` button.

Comment: Just put backticks around your code and post it

Comment: won't bother answering this, but look at the condition- it must be wrapped in parentheses and the semicolon at the end is extra

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could also add the error that the compiler gives - the section around the first "Caused by"

Answer (score 1):

In the third else statement, you have some parentheses missing. The entire boolean condition must be enclosed in parentheses. Also, you should use == instead of =, because == checks for equality, and = is the assignment operator. Also, the third else if statement has a semicolon instead of an opening curly brace at its end, and the statement directly following it needs a quotation mark, a parenthesis, and a semicolon added at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need `==` in the last `else if` not `=`

`=` is an assignment operator, whereas `==` checks for equality (with primitives).

Comment: this may be true, but there's WAY more than this one issue

Comment: +1, though "this is definitely true" but there's more than this one issue :P

Answer (score 0):

```
  else if (itemCount % BOXES != 0) && (itemCount % CARTONS != 0);
      System.out.println("Neither boxes nor cartons can be used for your: " + itemCount + " items. 
  else if (itemCount % BOXES = 0) && (itemCount % CARTONS = 0 );{
```

Should be this, without the semicolons after the else if statments.  You are saying your statement is done when you leave them in there and the compiler is confused by the next else statements.

EDIT: Also as the other answers talk about, wrap your ifs in parthesis, and you should use == when doing a comparison.

```
  else if ((itemCount % BOXES != 0) && (itemCount % CARTONS != 0))
      System.out.println("Neither boxes nor cartons can be used for your: " + itemCount + " items. 
  else if ((itemCount % BOXES == 0) && (itemCount % CARTONS = 0 )){
```

Answer (score 0):

Too may bracketing errors to keep track of them all. And you need to fix the `=` to `==` as mentioned my another ansewer. Here's the refactor. You can compare it with your current code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//This class ask a user for their item count and informs the user of the best packing method.
public class PackingOrganizer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//declare constants and variables
        int CARTONS = 4, BOXES = 5;
        double containerAmount;
        double containerAmount2;
//Get users item count
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of items : (All partial items are to be rounded up. ex. 6.5 items is rounded to 7 items)");
        double itemCount = input.nextDouble();

//Check to see if input is an integer value
        if (itemCount != (int) itemCount) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input round all partial numbers up");
        } //processing phase
        else if (itemCount % CARTONS == 0) {
            containerAmount = (itemCount / CARTONS);
            System.out.println("Cartons can be used. The " + itemCount + " items will require " + containerAmount + " cartons ");
        } else if (itemCount % BOXES == 0) {
            containerAmount = (itemCount / BOXES);
            System.out.println("Boxes can be used. The " + itemCount + " items will require " + containerAmount + " Boxes ");
        } else if ((itemCount % BOXES != 0)
                && (itemCount % CARTONS != 0)) {
            System.out.println("Neither boxes nor cartons can be used for your: " + itemCount + " items");
        } else if ((itemCount % BOXES == 0)
                && (itemCount % CARTONS == 0)) {

            containerAmount = (itemCount / BOXES);
            containerAmount2 = (itemCount / CARTONS);
            System.out.println("Cartons can be used. The " + itemCount + " items will require " + containerAmount2 + "." + " Boxes can be used. The " + itemCount + " items will require" + containerAmount + " boxes ");
        }
    }
}
```